# Salesforce react native APP by using mobile sdk integration always create app as a template

Tags: ios, react-native, salesforce, salesforce-communities, salesforce-mobile-sdk

We are using react-native salesforce mobileSDK version (8.3.0) by using Template. However when we compile the project we have encountered project compilation issue listed in the link

My question is that how can I use salesforce mobile sdk in react native without using above mentioned script or how can we implement react native mobile sdk in existing react native app?

It is always asking to add script in podfile for some libraries i.e aysnc storage or react-native-safe-area-context

post_install do |installer_representation|
installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

```
    #Workaround for Xcode 12 and Auto-Linking
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ['react-native-safe-area-context', 'RNGestureHandler', 'SalesforceReact'].include?(target.name) #list all affected target in the array
            target.build_phases.each do |build_phases|

                if build_phases.display_name == 'Frameworks'
                    file_ref = installer_representation.pods_project.new(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference)
                    file_ref.path = 'React.framework'
                    file_ref.source_tree = 'BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR'
                    build_phases.add_file_reference(file_ref)
                end
            end
        end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is that how can I use salesforce mobile sdk in react native without using above mentioned script or how can we implement react native mobile sdk in existing react native app?